# How can i validate the surroundings of a ship in Battleship game?

Tags: java, validation

This is supposed to prevent ship edges from touching other ships, but for some reason it doesn't work. Specially for my T shaped ship.
I think this has to do with the condition in the `for` loops, probably the `boat.getLength()+1` is not enough there, but i don't know what else to try.
My `mainBoard` length is 10x10 and the `line` and `col` parameters are supposed to be what we get from the user scanner. My board in its natural state is initialized with character '~'. Each boat when its positioned successfully it changes the '~' with the character appointed to that specific boat.

```
public boolean validateSurrounding(Boat boat, int line, int col) {

    int i = line;
    int j = col;

    for (i = i - 1; i < boat.getLength()+1; i++) {

        for (j = j - 1; j < boat.getLength()+1; j++) {
            if (i < 0 || i >= mainBoard.length || j < 0 || j >= mainBoard[0].length) {
                continue;
            }

            if (mainBoard[i][j] != '~') {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are damaging your inner loop starting condition.

```
int i = line;
int j = col;

for (i = i - 1; i < boat.getLength()+1; i++) {
    for (j = j - 1; j < boat.getLength()+1; j++) {
```

The second iteration of the outer loop, `j` will start at `boat.getLength()+1`, which is the last value it had during the outer loop's first execution.

Instead, use:

```
int i;
int j;

for (i = line - 1; i < boat.getLength()+1; i++) {
    for (j = col - 1; j < boat.getLength()+1; j++) {
```

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion helped me solve it. Apparently instead of boat.length() i have to use, line + 1 and col +1 , respectively.